# Como pegar o valor exato da divisão com as casas decimais depois da vírgula?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

Eu preciso fazer um cálculo de porcentagem, mas não estou conseguindo recuperar o valor exato.

Exemplo:

```
int valorUni = 8;

int valorTotal = 116;

double result;

result = (valorUni / valorTotal) * 100;
//Resultado esperado: 7,547169811320755
//Resultado que saí: 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazendo um *cast*:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int valorUni = 8;
        int valorTotal = 116;
        double result = ((double)valorUni / valorTotal) * 100;
        WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Z5Wvrc). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/maq1N7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/CastDouble.cs).

Se você manda dividir dois inteiros o resultado só pode ser inteiro, então precisa transformar pelo menos um deles em `double` para que o resultado tenha casas decimais.

Mas note que parece que está trabalhando com valor monetário. `double` não deve ser usado para valor monetário. Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

De qualquer forma não é para dar o resultado que está esperando.